# Would Sauron have had the ability to appear in fair form again if he got the ring back?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

In the First and Second Ages of Middle Earth, Sauron had the ability to change into an appealing form to Men and Elves.  He could then deceive them, and used the name of *Annatar*.  However, once he was on Numenor and the Island was destroyed, so was his fair form so he was subsequently trapped in his "hideous" form.

Since it is said that he was gaining much of his old strength back, would it have been possible for Sauron to regain the ability to appear fair to the peoples of Middle Earth again had he regained the ring from Frodo and Sam?

Answer (score 14):

We don't know for sure; as far as we know, he never tries.

However, Sauron loses the ability to assume a fair-seeming form during the destruction of Númenor:

> But Sauron was not of mortal flesh, and though he was robbed now of that shape in which he had wrought so great an evil, so that he could never again appear fair to the eyes of Men, yet his spirit arose out of the deep and passed as a shadow and a black wind over the sea, and came back to Middle-earth and to Mordor that was his home.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* IV *Akallabêth*</sup>

According to Appendix B, this occurs in S.A. 3319. The Ring was created *c.* S.A. 1600, so he had *already* made the Ring when he lost his fair-seeming form. It seems stunningly unlikely that recovering the Ring would put him at a higher level of power than when he was at in the Second Age, so I'm inclined to say no, he could not.

However, note that it only says he could not appear fair to *men*. He could, perhaps, still assume a form that seemed fair to Dwarves (for example), but we don't know.

Comment: Plus an extra one, if I could, for that last paragraph alone - only lost the ability to seem fair to men?  Oh, the implications!

Comment: Actually we do know because it says he never could again

Comment: @ulmo "he could never again appear fair to the eyes of Men" does not preclude appearing fair to other races; what a Man finds fair may not be the same thing a Dwarf (or an Ent, or any other kind of creature) would find fair

Comment: Hmm, that is an interesting point...seems a bit strange that it could depend on race. I saw this as an analogous thing that happened to morgoth. He invested all of his power into evil such that he was never again able to appear fair to anyone and maintained the shape of the tyrant of utumno. I feel like saurons experience mirrors this...but your point is taken

Comment: @ulmo Tolkien talks about that briefly in "Notes on Motives", in *Morgoth's Ring*. Sauron put much, *much* less of himself into the Ring (compared to what Morgoth put into Arda), which is why Morgoth was limited in ways Sauron wasn't

Comment: Besides I don't think his appearance would have bothered him if he reclaimed the ring Middle Earth was without a doubt his as master i dont think hed care

Comment: He may very well appear "fair" to Orcs, in whatever sense Orcs deem something "fair".  Of course, it's entirely possible that the "to men" bit is just a poetic flourish.  Something like "to all that walk upon Arda" may be more accurate, but lacks some of the pithy, succinct impact. And then we'd start going "well what about the Eagles and things that do not walk per se..."

Answer (score 12):

No. From Akallabeth: "he could never again appear fair to the eyes of men, yet his spirit arose out of the deep and passed as a shadow and a black wind over the sea back to middle earth". Note that after he returns to middle earth he is in possession of the ring, thus he cannot appear in fair form even with the ring.

Answer (score 0):

In a deleted scene from the final Peter Jackson film, Sauron demonstrates the ability to regain his "fair" form for a few brief seconds, just before his iconic fight with Aragorn.

There's no specific indication that possessing the One Ring would allow him to do so for longer, but by the same token I think we can assume that being uber-powerful couldn't possibly hurt his chances.

[image]

Comment: Don't blame me. The question doesn't say "books only, please".

Comment: That's edited or fanmade, that part never actually happened lol

Comment: see original https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtEC3pNEMhY

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Well, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C97qFHl0jVw) was the (released) alternative ending but the image of annatar was leaked as a set photo and then spliced into the footage. Since it's all based on Jackson material, I'm willing to leave it up.

Comment: According to the books, Illuvatar's wrath came swiftly upon Numenor at its downfall. To escape it, Sauron abandoned his fair form and quickly spirited himself away - apparate, if you will - to Middle Earth. His fair form was thus trapped with Numenor beneath the seas until the end of time, and that is why he cannot appear before the lesser races in his fair form forever. Note that fair form here refers to a tangible body made of matter - Sauron can no longer take a form similar to the Free Peoples, restricted instead to his present dark form. Planting thoughts in people's mind is different tho

Comment: @thegreatjedi no, he died in the collapse of Numenor and his spirit rose from the bottom of the see and returned to Middle-earth.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack To a mortal's eyes, maybe, but remember that he is not of this world. A Maiar's death is not as simple as "the spirit leaves the body". His fair form is just a physical manifestation - he does not need it to exist in Arda, but it helps his plans to use it. Illuvatar trapped it under the sea, so he is forced to abandon it if he wants to return to Middle Earth. Thereafter he can never use it again since he left it behind, so he can only manifest in "dark form". By a Maiar's definition, he is very much alive.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack Sauron only died in RotK, and even then that's subjective. Tolkien wrote "Sauron’s own being would be diminished to vanishing point, and he would be reduced to a shadow, a mere memory of malicious will". This shadow will forever hover over Mordor as nothing more than a dark cloud. It could be these are the very-much-dead remains of Sauron, but it may also be the remains of Sauron, still alive, forever unable to recover enough to be a threat again now that the One Ring is gone. Either way, death is still one-time for Maiars, pending Illuvatar's permission for rebirth

Comment: @thegreatjedi I'm using died to indicate the loss of his physical form. E difference between the later death is he'd lost the power to reform - even after the ring was destroyed he wasn't dead.

Comment: @thegreatjedi and you are mistaken about the one time only. Eru intervened with Gandalf and gave him a body to avoid the long recovery time in Valinor it would have taken to reform.

Comment: Jedi youve got it wrong.His original physical body was destroyed at Numenor his spirit arose and carried the ring to Mordor where he wrought a new body which was unable to be fair because of how long hed been evil.His original form was wrought in the time when he was a maia and totally uncorrupted.

Comment: Your video link has gone dead.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's the second time. Grr. I'll dump an image instead.

Answer (score 0):

No he wouldn't,he had the ring when he left Numenor and was unable to wrought himself a fair semblance because he'd been immersed in evil for too long and as far as i know he was at his full strength then.

Answer (score -2):

Surely he wouldn't bother to appear 'fair' if he had the Power of the One Ring - not the sort of entity to bother with niceties.